# CSS full width header (Full width, cannot see body background)

Tags: html, css, web

I've seen this question asked many times but when I try to implement their solution it doesn't seem to work.

I am currently starting to dabble in HTML and CSS using an external stylesheet.

I created a container with the following (borders are only to help me learn about containers):

```css
header{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 background: lightgrey;
 border: solid red;
}

header>h1{
 color:black;
 border: solid blue;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header>p{
 font-style: italic;
 text-align: left;
 color:white;
 border: solid yellow;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>My Web Space</h1>
 <p> First HTML Page using Sublime Text</p>
</header>
```

However, when I run it in a web page, the width of the header is not 100% of the browser window. I can still see some slime fraction of the body background (in this case coloured red) on the top, left and right sides).

I set the height and background for `sliderhomepage` to present the effect

Comment: How do you know you're seeing the background and not the border since they are both red?

Comment: That's a vestige of when I had a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you css :

```
    *{
margin:0;
padding:0:
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
}
header{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background: lightgrey;
    border:2px  solid red;
}
```

See it working:

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0:
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
}
header{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    background: lightgrey;
    border:2px  solid red;
}

header>h1{
    color:black;
    border: solid blue;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header>p{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    color:white;
    border: solid yellow;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>My Web Space</h1>
    <p> First HTML Page using Sublime Text</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! 

So just to make sure I properly understood, the wildcard '*' character selects all elements and removes padding?

Comment: yes, exactly. can you please accept  my answer then.

Comment: Depending on your uses, removing margin/padding from *all* elements might have some ill effects. A more basic fix might just give 0 margin/padding to the `html` and `body` elements.

Comment: well. the point is not to fix just this problem. many problems on SO are because of unexpected structure break due to margin/padding on elements

Comment: it's more effective that we set all to `0` and use them as we need them. using classes reduce your work .

Comment: on  a page you don't need as much classes as number of elements so it's a win afterall

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have not set any of the body or document margins or styles.

You need to set hr margin and padding to 0 for the body or global selector.

```
 *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f4x4dm09/2/

Comment: Thank you, makes a lot of sense! Is it common practice to set initialize your margins and styles before (didn't read about it in the tutorials I've found so far). Also, is this something that is taken into account when working with a CSS framework?

Comment: Yea.  It's common and best practice to initialize everything to 0 so you have a blank slate. Most frameworks do this, such as Bootstrap.